# What aircraft "don't respond well to tarmac runways"?

Tags: grass-field

On the [Shoreham Airfield Website](http://flybrighton.com) they wrote, they have a tarmac runway for most aircraft and a grass strip (actually two) for "aircraft which need a grass strip".

Quote:

> We appreciate that older, more fragile planes don’t respond well to tarmac and that’s why we offer both grass and tarmac runways to cater for a wide range of aircraft.

[Page link](http://flybrighton.com/fly-with-us/airport-information-for-pilots/)

- What aircraft are those not responding well to tarmac? What does it mean they don't respond well to tarmac? I could imagine this to be old WW2 Aircraft or similar.

Comment: My first thought would be a glider aircraft

Comment: Some sea planes that need servicing but don't have wheels need to land on grass strips to avoid damaging the pontoons. [Here is an example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MR483bK_6Js).

Comment: @Brilsmurfffje most modern gliders have wheels and *could* land on concrete/asphalt but it takes some time to taxi them away from the runway... ;o)

Comment: I would think that some WW I era biplanes that had a tail skid instead of a tail wheel would be happier landing on grass or dirt. e.g. The Curtis Jenny doesn‘t appear to have a tailwheel but there are pictures of it landing on a paved surface.

Comment: @RonBeyer Impressive.

Comment: Shoreham is a nice airfield, a very picturesque approach over the coast.

Comment: @GdD So true, two hours ago I bought the scenery for flight sim :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No airplanes absolutely need a grass strip, but for some taildraggers (airplanes which have a tailskid instead of a wheel) it's a real benefit because the grass is softer on the skid, and the friction of the grass improves control on the ground and helps slow the plane down. Pavement isn't that big a problem for skids make from more modern materials, but you can imagine it's not going to do a slab of wood much good. Many vintage designs have no brakes or poor brakes, so having grass makes a big difference when landing, on pavement you'd end up rolling a lot longer and have less directional control at low speed.

Comment: Being "kinder" to the skid isn't the only factor: the skid is actually important for steering on the ground, as the rudder doesn't have enough authority at low speeds. On a hard runway where the skid can't dig in, you have little steering control, and a stiff breeze can turn you into wind with no way to recover..